# Why location.state gets undefined when the page reloads?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm working on a project with react and i'm doing a simple `history.push()` just to navigate to another component. Beside navigating to the other component i'm passion some data by using `history.push({state: []})`.

To access the data to the other component I use `useLocation()` and access it with location.state.
I switch the language on the app (the language logic is set with `setLocalStorage()`) and suddenly the `location.state` gets `undefined`.
I read in some articles that `location.state` gets undefined on re render. I didn't find something clear that specify that, not even on the `react-router-dom` documentation. Also when I reload the page the `location.state` doesn't become `undefined`.

My question is why does it happen when the page is re render.?
Is it the best practice to pass the data like this? If not which is the best practice to pass it to another component so these errors can be avoid?

LanguageDropdown

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Dropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
import classNames from 'classnames';

import enFlag from './flags/uk.jpg';
import italyFlag from './flags/italy.jpg';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

// get the languages
const Languages = [
  {
    name: 'English',
    flag: enFlag,
    short_name: 'en'
  },
  {
    name: 'Italian',
    flag: italyFlag,
    short_name: 'it'
  }
];

const LanguageDropdown = () => {
  const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [selectedLanguage, setSelectedLanguage] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem('defaultLang') !== null
      ? Languages.find(function (item: { name: string; flag: string; short_name: string }) {
          return item.short_name == localStorage.getItem('defaultLang');
        })
      : Languages[0]
  );

  const [t, i18n] = useTranslation('common');
  /*
   * toggle language-dropdown
   */
  const toggleDropdown = () => {
    setDropdownOpen(!dropdownOpen);
  };

  const changeLanguage = async (lang: any) => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(lang.short_name);
    setSelectedLanguage(lang);
    localStorage.setItem('defaultLang', lang.short_name);
  };

  return (
    <Dropdown show={dropdownOpen} onToggle={toggleDropdown}>
      <Dropdown.Toggle
        id='dropdown-languages'
        as='a'
        onClick={toggleDropdown}
        className={classNames('nav-link waves-effect waves-light', {
          show: dropdownOpen
        })}>
         <img src={selectedLanguage.flag} alt={selectedLanguage.name} height='16' />
      </Dropdown.Toggle>
      <Dropdown.Menu className='dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end'>
        <div onClick={toggleDropdown}>
          {(Languages || []).map((lang, i) => {
            return (
              <Link
                to='#'
                onClick={() => changeLanguage(lang)}
                className='dropdown-item notify-item'
                key={i + '-lang'}>
                <img src={lang.flag} alt={lang.name} className='me-1' height='12' />
                <span className='align-middle'>{lang.name}</span>
              </Link>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
};

export default LanguageDropdown;
```

Comment: Does the page reload or just the component rerenders?

Comment: Passing route state and accessing `location.state` is all you need. Do you have some other logic that is issuing *another* navigation change when navigating? What is the "switch the language on the app"? Can you [edit] the post to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant routing and navigation code you are using, including whatever is changing language, so we can see what the code is doing, and when it does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue appears to be the link targets used in the language selection dropdowns. They issue a navigation action to `"/#"` sans any existing state. This is the route state being wiped out.

## Solution

Instead of navigating to `"/#"` you may just navigate to the current location

```
const LanguageDropdown = () => {
  const location = useLocation(); // <-- current location, including any state

  ...

  return (
    <Dropdown show={dropdownOpen} onToggle={toggleDropdown}>
      ...
      <Dropdown.Menu className='dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end'>
        <div onClick={toggleDropdown}>
          {(Languages || []).map((lang, i) => {
            return (
              <Link
                to={location} // <-- current location, including any state
                onClick={() => changeLanguage(lang)}
                className='dropdown-item notify-item'
                key={i + '-lang'}
              >
                ...
              </Link>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
};

export default LanguageDropdown;
```

If you are effectively staying on the current page though, you could also just omit the `to` prop and cancel the navigation action.

```
const LanguageDropdown = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <Dropdown show={dropdownOpen} onToggle={toggleDropdown}>
      ...
      <Dropdown.Menu className='dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end'>
        <div onClick={toggleDropdown}>
          {(Languages || []).map((lang, i) => {
            return (
              <Link
                onClick={(e) => {
                  e.preventDefault(); // <-- prevent navigation action
                  changeLanguage(lang);
                }}
                className='dropdown-item notify-item'
                key={i + '-lang'}
              >
                ...
              </Link>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
};

export default LanguageDropdown;
```

### Demo

[image: Edit why-location-state-gets-undefined-when-the-page-reloads]

Comment: Yes you are correct. Thank you. To be honest I understood it when I add the code in here. I notice the ```<Link to='#'/ >```. In my case I just put ```<button>``` instead of ``` <Link/>```, but your answer more smooth solution.

Comment: @Mario Sure, I was tempted to mention that at this point rendering multiple links that all link to the same target path is a little pointless, but maybe you were using links for the rendered UI so didn't think it relevant to the issue of state persistence. For sure a button works as well.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are observing where location.state becomes undefined on re-render is related to how React Router handles state objects passed via history.push(). The state is not intended to persist across re-renders of a component. Instead, it is meant to be used for passing temporary data from one route to another, and it doesn't persist through navigation within the same route.

The location.state object is tied to the specific route you are navigating to. When you change the language using setLocalStorage(), it may trigger a re-render of the current component. If you are relying on location.state to persist between re-renders, it may appear as if it's becoming undefined because it's not a reliable way to store persistent data.

you can go for other alternatives:
If you need to persist data between page reloads, you can use localStorage or sessionStorage to store and retrieve data. This can be useful for storing user preferences like the selected language.

Comment: `location.state` ***is*** persisted between component renders. Here's a running [sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/why-location-state-gets-undefined-when-the-page-reloads-wqftn3?file=/src/App.js) where the passed route state persists *even though* the child and parent components rerender. Your reasoning and explanation don't quite fit here. There's something else going on in the OP's code.